# JQuery AJAX callback troughs an error

Tags: jquery

I am getting an error at the success: method of the .ajax function of the JQuery.

MyService.asmx:

```
 [WebMethod]
        public FileInfo[] GetFileInfo(int Id)
        {
            Proxies.ServiceRef.ServiceClient c = new Proxies.ServiceRef.ServiceClient();
            return c.GetFileInfo(Id).ToArray();
        }
```

The Jquery code where I am getting error :

```
          $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: jsonData,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: _I.contentType,
                timeout: _I.timeout,
                dataType: "serviceproxy",  // custom type to avoid double parse
                dataFilter: function (jsonString, type) {
                    if (type == "serviceproxy") {
                        // Use json library so we can fix up dates        
                        var res = JSON.parseWithDate(jsonString);
                        if (res && res.hasOwnProperty("d"))
                            res = res.d;
                        return res;
                    }
                    return jsonString;
                },
                ***success: function (result) {
                    if (callback)
                        callback(result);***
                }
                   error: function(xhr, error).......
```

});

When I debug using firebug the response is as follows.  What I noticed is that my error callback is fired every time. Can anybody explain what's wrong?

```
{"d":[{"__type":"Proxies.AFARServiceRef.AssignmentInfo","ExtensionData":{},"AssignDate":"\/Date(1317748587667)\/","AssignFileName":null,"ClaimId":"PA026195","ClaimantName":"Rachel Weiss","FirstContactDate":"\/Date(1302678000000)\/","FirstContactTime":{"Ticks":433800000000,"Days":0,"Hours":12,"Milliseconds":0,"Minutes":3,"Seconds":0,"TotalDays":0.50208333333333333,"TotalHours":12.049999999999999,"TotalMilliseconds":43380000,"TotalMinutes":723,"TotalSeconds":43380},"Id":5257,"InspectionDate":"\/Date(1302246000000)\/","StatusId":1,"SubmittedCount":5,"UploadedCount":9}]}
```

Thanks

BB

Answer (score 1):

Your missing the `{}` brackets for the `if` function in the success callback and a comma after the success callback.

```
success: function (result) {
  if (callback){
    callback(result);
  }
},
error: function(xhr, error)
```